# How to extract column in R function using variable name?

Tags: r, statistics

In the below function I reference the dataframe "data", which has two columns called "nitrate" and "dust". The pollutant argument is a string (either "nitrate" or "dust".)  But for some reason when I call the function I run into a problem with the "data$pollutant" line. Likewise,

```
pollutant <- "nitrate"
data$pollutant
```

Throws an error. But,

```
data$nitrate
```

Works fine

```
is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
> pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332)
{
 sum = 0
 length = 0
 listCSV <- list.files()[id]
 for (i in listCSV) 
 {
 data <- read.csv(i) 
 no_missing <- data[!is.na(data$pollutant),]
 sum = sum + sum(no_missing$pollutant)
 length = length + length(no_missing$pollulant) 
 }

 sum/length

}
```

Thanks!
-Steve

Comment: The linked duplicate goes over this in more detail, but you're looking for `data[,pollutant]`.

Comment: Or  `data[[pollutant]]`. This isn't really a duplicate of the linked question, since this is asking about `data.frame`s and the other question is about  matrices and extraction works differently.